# Pandas Scrape switching values on scrape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, python-requests

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

urls = [
    'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/play_by_play/12465',
    'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/play_by_play/12755',
    'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/play_by_play/12640',
    'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/play_by_play/12290',
]
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
for url in urls:
    r = s.get(url)
    dfs = pd.read_html(r.text)
    for df in dfs:
        df.to_csv('pbp.csv', mode='a', index=False)
```

I have this amazing script I've struggled through (with the help of this community).  It pulls the table data from these different sites, and pushes to a CSV.

For some reason, the "Score" in some places loses it's format (Image below).  I've tried formatting in Excel/Sheets, but no luck.

I don't see anything different in Inspector with these lines -- it's not all of them, only a select few on each link.

Any way I could prevent this from happening? Doesn't make much sense to me.

[image: Incorrect Score]

Comment: As stated, excel will auto convert and thinks its a date. Few ways to prevent this. 1) don't open in excel to view, find a different viewer to look at the csv. 2) convert that column in the dataframe to be enclosed in quotes. This will prevent excel from thinking it's a date.

Comment: @chitown88 opening in notepad still creates an issue with the score.  I'm trying to follow different questions to add the quotes into my script, but neither answer really explains how it's fixed & I can't figure out how to apply it to mine.  Any suggestions on how it could be done?

Comment: thats interesting that notepad would also do that.  Actually, what I think would be better than adding the quotes, is spiting that into 2 columns. Give me a minute to code that up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking about it further, you can keep the values a integers and not having it confused as a date object if we just split the column. I also separated each game into separate files as well.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

urls = [
    'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/play_by_play/12465',
    'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/play_by_play/12755',
    'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/play_by_play/12640',
    'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/play_by_play/12290',
]
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
for url in urls:
    gameId = url.split('/')[-1]
    r = s.get(url)
    dfs = pd.read_html(r.text)
    for df in dfs:
        if len(df.columns) > 2:
            if df.iloc[0,2] == 'Score':
                df[4] = df[3]
                df[[2,3]] = df[2].str.split('-', expand=True)
         
        df.to_csv('pbp_%s.csv' %gameId, mode='a', index=False)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Ah!! I see - this is great. Amazing solution - I don't entirely understand but am looking into each bit of code you added.  Amazing

Comment: so `.iloc()` can be used to look at a specific row index and column index. Since you are combining all the tables together, we need to wait til we get to the table that has the text `"Score"` in the first row, in the 3rd column (so row index 0, column index 2). Once we get to that table, we move over the index column 3 to 4, (to make room) for splitting column 2 (on the `'-'`) into two columns, which will go into columns 2 and 3. Does make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it's converting the scores to dates, no? Maybe you can cast that column to string?

`dfs = pd.read_html(r.text, converters={'Score': lambda x: str(x)})`

I'd try that...

Comment: unfortunately I'm still getting the dates, but this is useful.  Hoping I can play with other layouts off this - any other suggestions?